# ReactJS controlled select box validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<select 
name="destination" 
className="form-control"
onChange={ this.handleDestination }>
<option value=""> - { translations.destination_town } -</option>
{
    destinationTowns.map( (town, index) => {
        return <option key={ index } value={ town.id }>{ town.name }</option>
    })
}
```

How do i validate this select box let's say for instance, if the user has not selected any option, pass an error message that the field is required?

Comment: Because you have already a function in your onchange event, you can get value then check if it's empty then you can use `setState`

Comment: @SachiTekina i am using some library https://github.com/chriso/validator.js to validate.. basically how this works is you pass in the field to validate and a rule i.e isEmpty for my case then a message if the validation check resolves to false.. i could use `setState` but i don't know how it works with this library

Comment: You can do this without the validator.js library. Kindly include what you have done, like the function `handleDestination `

Comment: @SachiTekina `handleDestination = (e) => {

        const { quote } = this.state;
        const { options, value, selectedIndex } = e.target;

        this.setState({
            quote: {
                ...quote,
                destination: {
                    id: value,
                    town: options[selectedIndex].text
                }
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: I created a mock script on how to do it, this might help: https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/30498/